# Standard 401 response when using HTTP auth in flask

Tags: python, apache2, flask, http-authentication, abort

In flask, I'm using the following [snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/) to enable HTTP auth:

```
def authenticate():
    return Response('<Why access is denied string goes here...>', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate':'Basic realm="Login Required"'})
```

Now, in my past experience with Flask, if someone's credentials are incorrect and I want to let them know I can just call:

```
abort(401)
```

This gives you the basic apache 401 response. Does anyone know how I can implement that with the snippet above?

Thanks

Comment: In case you have different reasons for different 401s, `abort(401, '<Why access is denied string goes here...>')` will also work.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Custom error responses are really quite easy in Flask.  Create a function whose only argument is the HTTP error status code, make it return a flask.Response instance, and decorate it with [@app.errorhandler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler).

```
@app.errorhandler(401)
def custom_401(error):
    return Response('<Why access is denied string goes here...>', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate':'Basic realm="Login Required"'})
```

You can then use `abort(401)` to your heart's content.

Comment: This needs to be ''WWW-Authenticate'' (with the dash!) to properly work in the browser.

Comment: So it does. Fixed.

Answer (score 18):

Flask's `abort` comes directly from Werkzeug. It is a callable object, that raises various predefined HTTP exceptions (subclasses of `HTTPException`) on demand. Check out the code [here](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/src/werkzeug/exceptions.py) for details.

The predefined `Unauthorized` (which is mapped to 401) only defines the code and a message, but not the `WWW-Authenticate` header, which as you know is required to trigger the login-popup with browsers. The headers an `HTTPException` has are hardcoded as `[('Content-Type', 'text/html')]` in `HTTPException.get_headers`.

So to add the `WWW-Authenticate` header, create your own `Unauthorized` subclass, overwrite the `get_headers` function and finally update the `abort.mapping` dictionary with it.

```
from flask import abort
from werkzeug.exceptions import Unauthorized

class MyUnauthorized(Unauthorized):
    description = '<Why access is denied string goes here...>'
    def get_headers(self, environ):
        """Get a list of headers."""
        return [
            ('Content-Type', 'text/html'),
            ('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Login required"'),
        ]

abort.mapping.update({401: MyUnauthorized})
```

Now all `abort(401)` calls will raise your custom exception.