# Is there a way to intercept a 401 status code from flask_jwt_extended and return this value?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-jwt-extended

So I have a JWT token being generated and after 10 minutes it expires. Once it expires, I want to be able to catch this 401 error code. I am using flask_jwt_extended library. This is my code:

```
@dossier_blueprint.route("/week", methods=["GET"])
@jwt_required
# @app.cache.cached(timeout=800)
def get_dossier_created_this_week():
    return dossier_service.query_aantal_dossiers_deze_week_bvcm_c2c()
```

Comment: See this for custom error responses, which has 401 as an example on the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877230/standard-401-response-when-using-http-auth-in-flask.

Comment: @jon but flask_jwt_extended gives his own error precedence above my global error exception which you can find in the link you have given.

Comment: maybe try registering a custom handler and setting app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423580/errorhandler-not-firing-when-debug-is-false